# compare lines in JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextarea

Im working on a project where I create an online-shop-like application. Have everything working apart from last thing, which is reading the whole basket(items added to basket)

I have a button that adds item to the order(they are displayed in jtextarea).
I have another button that finishes shopping and is supposed to print your items which were added to jtextarea. Unfortunately I was only able to figure out how to read the last line in jtextarea. so basically what happens :

> customer orders x, amount 1
>    customer orders y, amount 3
>    customer orders z, amount 7

It will only print the last line. any suggestion?
Here is the code

````
        btnFinish.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                int end = textArea.getDocument().getLength();
                int start = 0;
                try {
                    start = Utilities.getRowStart(textArea, end);
                } catch (BadLocationException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                while (start == end)
                {
                    end--;
                    try {
                        start = Utilities.getRowStart(textArea, end);
                    } catch (BadLocationException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                String text = null;
                try {
                    text = textArea.getText(start, end - start);
                } catch (BadLocationException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("(" + text + ")");  ```
````

Comment: For better help sooner post a proper [mre], I see nowhere in that snippet that you're setting / appending anything to the `textArea`. Also a better approach would be to have a model that gets updated and the UI just reflects what the model has

Comment: Shouldn't this `while (start == end)` be `while (start != end)`? Your code is really confusing, specially without more context

Comment: You should be maintaining the order it a seperate model (like a `List`).  You would then use the UI elements to display this model in what ever fashion you like.  However, you could just get the `text` from the `JTextArea` and `split` it on the line break